# Work needed to orbit earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, orbital-motion, satellites

In school I have always been told that it's better to launch spacecrafts from around the equator to utilize earth's rotation.

Now, when wanting to theoretically put a large object with a lot of mass into orbit, the required work was considered. It was said that we can neglect the spacecraft's kinetic energy it receives due to earth's rotation and only calculate the potential and kinetic energy in the orbit, and from earth only the potential energy. To then calculate the change in energy overall.

I am not sure why though. Does anyone have an explanation? Is that energy not important?

Comment: Related/duplicate [How much of an advantage do equator-proximal launch sites provide?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/998/how-much-of-an-advantage-do-equator-proximal-launch-sites-provide)